# Xarray: is there a neat way to reduce entire dataset dimension size x and y without changing datatype for variables?

Tags: dataset, python-xarray

I'm trying to reduce my xarray dataset dimension  (x and y)  by one, e.g. 257x257 to 256x256.

This code is what I have tried:

```
if cube.dims['x'] > patch_size:
    cube=cube.where((cube.y<cube.y.data.max()) & (cube.x<cube.x.max()),drop=True)
```

if cube.dims['x'] > patch_size:
cube=cube.where((cube.y<cube.y.data.max()) & (cube.x<cube.x.max()),drop=True)

When I run this code, all variables change the data type to float64 (probably because where() statement converts to "nan" while selecting data).
Is there a better way of doing this without changing the data type to float64?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than masking and dropping the data with where, simply select the data you want along the x and y dimensions. This will be faster than masking with `where`, and will get around the `int->float` type promotion problem you're seeing.

You could do this a number of ways, e.g. with [`.sel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sel.html) for label-based indexing or [`.isel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.isel.html) for positional indexing. Since you're trying to extract all but the last indices, I'll use `isel` with `slice`:

```py
cube = cube.isel(y=slice(None, -1), x=slice(None, -1))
```

This could also be done with sel, using filtered coordinates as you have in your question:

```py
ds.sel(x=(ds.x < ds.x.max()), y=(ds.y < ds.y.max()))
```

Both of these methods will work with both DataArray and Datasets.

If you're working with a DataArray, you could also do this by referring to the dimensions positionally with [`.loc`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.loc.html) - just be careful when doing this because xarray doesn't always preserve dimension ordering:

```py
cube = cube.loc[:-1, :-1]
```

Referring to dimensions by order like this is not allowed for datasets.

See the [xarray docs on Indexing and Selecting Data](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/indexing.html) for more info on this topic.

#### Note on type promotion with .where

While the above is going to perform better for your specific case, you've raised an interesting issue about what I think is an unnecessary limitation of `DataArray.where`. I think there's no reason why you couldn't set a custom `other` fill value when using `.where` with `drop=True`. Currently, this is prohibited by an assertion in xarray - I've raised an issue here to see if we can fix this: [gh#6466](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6466).

Comment: thank you for the answer. but unfortunately, positional indexing is not possible on a dataset (says 'not available' on the link) so the two methods you mentioned does not work for me.

Comment: Hmm. isel is available for datasets: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.isel.html#xarray.Dataset.isel. Does this work for you? I did think we were talking about a DataArray - it’s best if you can try to create a [mre] to clearly communicate what you’re working with :)

Comment: updated to accommodate dataset and dataarray. .isel and .sel answers above work with both.